# Get the icon of the source app of an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

in my app I would like to get the icon of the app which from the user triggered the intent. For example when sharing site url from google chrome I would like to get the chrome icon. I have found something here on stackoverflow and it seems like this will be little bit tricky. 
The problem is I am using an IntentService in the part of my app where I need the icon and I dont know how to manage `getCallingActivity` be working in this context. It also won't work if the intent wouldn't be called with `startActivityForResult`, I guess..

So please does anyone from you know about reliable solution how to get the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example when sharing site url from google chrome I would like to get the chrome icon

That is not possible, because you have no way to know what used the `Intent`.

Comment: Hm..Bad news. I got untaught that on Android anything could be not possible, the platform is just so great.
and what about, getting the most recent task from task stack via task manager. I know, that is completely wrong approach, but it just could work for me. (I pretend anyone would never call my intent programatically from background or so:)

Comment: @simekadam: You are certainly welcome to try that, but since the only code that will be invoking your `IntentService` is your own code, you should already know what the icon is. Random apps like Chrome don't call `startService()` on random `Intent` objects. Chrome might call `startActivity()` on something in your app, or might call `sendBroadcast()` that gets picked up by your app, but not `startService()`.

Comment: Hm I got lost in my code..I totally forgot thats me who starts the service:/ Working on this after quite long break. I have somethink like routingActivity which handles the initial intent and forwards it to the service. There I can possibly use the getCallingActivity method, but only if it would be called with startActivity for result, which is very unlikely, or even impossible to happen (I am not sure how this exactly works). Thank you for your help!